# The member "RESX member" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf

While I'm making a WPF program, I encountered "XDG0012 The member  is not recognized or is not accessible"
I checked if my Localization.resx is well set(Access=Public) and have such elements. And everything was OK.
Most weird thing is this:
[XAML code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQxw9.png)

Some of them have error and some of them are not. Even they defined in same resx file and accessed in same xaml file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Self Answer:
When I just make code that make error as comment, build and remove comment(remove ), problem was solved.
I'm glad to solve it but I still wonder why this error took place...

Comment: Which visual studio version you are using?

Comment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019